# How to print any math calculation on python under two "for" function?

Tags: python

I'm new on python and I couldnt understand why this code doesnt working.
In the code I'm trying to calibrate my leds, floor number + unit number should assign to number of led.

```
floors = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
unitperfloor = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10


for i in floors:
    for j in unitperfloor:
        numberofpixel = unitperfloor[j] + ((floors[i] - 1) * 92)
        print("floor:" + str(floors[i]) + " unit: " + str(unitperfloor[j]) + " = " + str(numberofpixel))
```

I tried to print only `i`, `j` and I see its working properly. But when I add this `numberofpixel` calculation, its looping just for 1 time.

Comment: Please look at your variables. These should be lists.

Comment: I tried but same,i looping for 1 time

Comment: What do you expect `unitperfloor[j]` to be when `j` becomes `10`?

Comment: I forgot add 11 to end of the unitperfloor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
floors=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
unitperfloor=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


for i in floors:
    for j in unitperfloor:
        numberofpixel = j + ((i- 1) * 92)
        print("floor:{} unit: {} = {}".format(i,j,numberofpixel))
```

For fetches the value of the list element, not the index of the list.

```
floors=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
unitperfloor=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10


for i in range(len(floors)):
    for j in range(len(unitperfloor)):
        numberofpixel = unitperfloor[j] + ((floors[i] - 1) * 92)
        print("floor:" + str(floors[i]) + " unit: " + str(unitperfloor[j]) + " = " + str(numberofpixel))
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why my code didnt worked?

Comment: Python's for statement fetches elements, like iterators, unlike other languages.

Comment: If you want the index use `for i in enumerate(floors):`

Comment: I think I have to leave my mind from c++ while working on python :) Thank you again!